# Download de dados em formato String e Imagens JPG

Tags: ios, web-service, objective-c, core-data, http-request

Estou implementando um projeto, que possui um Web Service. Neste Web Service são salvos dados de produtos, contendo os campos: Nome, Valor, Descrição e a Imagem do produto.

Fiz alguns testes baixando somente os dados no formato String, que devido a natureza dos dados, permite um download rápido.

A idéia do projeto, é que esses dados baixados sejam salvos no Core Data, onde já estou realizando com sucesso somente com os dados no formato String.

Porém, o download de imagens, somente retorna a URL de onde está armazenada a imagem, tendo que ser feito um request independente.

Para as imagens, irei salva-las em no diretório do app, e salvar o endereço da em disco (path file) no Core Data, e não a URL e nem o arquivo de imagem no formato Blob.

Porém tentei incluir o request da imagem dentro do looping que salva os arquivos no Core Data, porém devido a diferentes velocidades do download, estou tendo problemas ao realizar o download das imagens.

Para tentar solucionar este problema dividi o request em duas partes, um request para dados em formato String e outro para as imagens, criei duas classes para tratar os isso de maneira independente.

Para integrar as classes, inseri a requisição da imagem dentro do looping que faz requisição dos dados String. Porém devido ao tempo de download entre as duas, o looping que é um FOR dispara e finaliza antes do download da primeira imagem, o que gera um erro de lógica adicionando os endereços de discos das imagens de maneira errada.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para este problema?

Gostaria de saber como faço para partilhar os arquivos das classes, para que possa ser avaliado. Pois aqui ficaria muito grande.

Classe: GDRequestURL
Utilidade: Baixar os dados formato String e retornar um Array contendo o dicionário dos dados baixados.

GDRequestURL.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "URLGloblal.h"
    #import "GDResquestURLImage.h"
    @interface GDRequestURL : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate>{
        NSMutableData *responseData;
        NSMutableDictionary *result;
        NSMutableArray*cleanArray;
        NSString* isPizza;
        NSString* isMassa;
        NSString* isRodizio;
        NSString* isBebidas;
        NSString* isEventos;
        // Download de imagem
        //GDResquestURLImage* imageRequest;
       }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* url;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* requestToken;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* httpHeader;
    -(void)getDataFromURL;
    -(NSMutableArray*)retornaResultado;
    @end
```

GDRequestURL.m

```
#import "GDRequestURL.h"

@implementation GDRequestURL
- (id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        isEventos = urlEventos;
        isPizza   = urlPizzas;
        isMassa   = urlMassas;
        isBebidas = urlBebidas;
        isRodizio = urlBebidas;

        _requestToken = urlGlobalToken;
        _httpHeader = urlGlobalHttpHeader;


        // Passo 1 Download image
        GDResquestURLImage*imageRequest = [[GDResquestURLImage alloc] init];
        [imageRequest getImageFromURL];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)getDataFromURL{

    // Aqui é executado todo os métodos desta classe e retorna o resultado da consulta em forma de NSMutableDictionary.
    // Here runs all the methods of this class and returns the query result in the form of NSMutableDictionary.

    [self requestURLApi:_url requestValue:_requestToken httpHeaderField:_httpHeader];

    NSLog(@"getDataFromURL");

}



-(void)requestURLApi:(NSString *)requestURLString requestValue:(NSString*)value httpHeaderField:(NSString*)headFiedl{

     NSLog(@"requestURLApi");


    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURLString]];

    [req setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:headFiedl];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    [conn start];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

       NSLog(@"Connection pega data");

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
     NSError* error;

    [responseData appendData:data];

    result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Connection did finish loading");
     // Aqui deve ser implementada a logica para descompactação dos dados de seu JSON.
     // Mantenha a lógica apenas acrecentando campos (chaves) conforme o seu JSON gerado na Goldark

     // Here the logic should be implemented for unpacking the data from your JSON.
     // Keep logic just prepending the name and fields (keys) as your JSON generated in Goldark

    // Este modelo é somente para exemplo.
    // This model is only for example.

#pragma mark - Se Pizzas
    if([isPizza isEqual:_url]){
    // Recebe o array Data
    NSMutableArray* arrayDataReceived =  [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    cleanArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for ( NSMutableDictionary* valuesDict in arrayDataReceived) {

        NSMutableDictionary* cleanDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"nome"] forKey:@"nome"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"valorquarto"]forKey:@"valorquarto"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"valormedio"]forKey:@"valormedio"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"valorgrande"]forKey:@"valorgrande"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"descricao"]forKey:@"descricao"];

        // Pega URL da imagem baixa e salva em disco e retorna o path em disco para o Core Data.

       // GDResquestURLImage*imageRequest = [[GDResquestURLImage alloc] init];
       //  imageRequest.urlImage = [valuesDict objectForKey:@"imagem"];
       // [imageRequest getImageFromURL];

       // [cleanDict setObject:  [imageRequest  retornaImagem] forKey:@"imagem"];

            // Armazena os dicionarios em um Array
        [cleanArray addObject:cleanDict];

     }
       //  NSLog(@"%@",cleanArray);
   }
}

-(NSMutableArray*)retornaResultado{
    NSLog(@"retorna resultado");
    NSMutableArray* array =[ [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:cleanArray];
    return array;
}
@end
```

Abaixo está a classe responsável por baixar as imagens, ela é idêntica a de String.
Tem as mesma funcionalidade, baixar as imagens, salvar em disco e retornar o file path para o arquivo de imagem em disco.

GDRequestURLImage.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GDResquestURLImage : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate>{
NSMutableData *responseData;
NSMutableDictionary *result;
UIImage* imagemRecebida;
NSString *caminhoImagemEmDisco;
NSMutableDictionary* dicionarioCaminhoImagemEmDisco;
int numero;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* urlImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* requestToken;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* httpHeader;

-(void)getImageFromURL;
-(NSString*)retornaImagem;

-(id)initWithURLToRequest:(NSString*)urlImage requestValue:(NSString*)requestToken httpHeaderField:(NSString*)httpHeader;

@end
```

GDRequestURLImage.m

```
#import "GDResquestURLImage.h"


@interface GDResquestURLImage ()

@end

@implementation GDResquestURLImage
-(id)initWithURLToRequest:(NSString*)urlImage requestValue:(NSString*)requestToken httpHeaderField:(NSString*)httpHeader {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        numero = 0;

        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlImage]];

        [req setValue:requestToken forHTTPHeaderField:httpHeader];

        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

        [conn start];



    }

    return self;
}


-(void)getImageFromURL{

    // Aqui é executado todo os métodos desta classe e retorna o resultado da consulta em forma de NSMutableDictionary.
    // Here runs all the methods of this class and returns the query result in the form of NSMutableDictionary.

    [self requestURLApi:_urlImage requestValue:_requestToken httpHeaderField:_httpHeader];

    NSLog(@"1 -Inicio de download de imagem...\n");
}

-(void)requestURLApi:(NSString *)requestURLString requestValue:(NSString*)value httpHeaderField:(NSString*)headFiedl{

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURLString]];

    [req setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:headFiedl];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    [conn start];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSLog(@"2 - Connection DidReceiveData.\n");

    // As imagens ja vem em formato binario, portanto basta passar para responder (Tipo: NSMutableData).

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [responseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"3 - ConnectionFinishLoading.\n");
    NSLog(@"Fim de conexao");

    for (UIImage* imagemTemp in responseData) {

    imagemRecebida = [[UIImage alloc]init];

    imagemRecebida = imagemTemp;

    // paga endereço da pasta
    NSString* enderecoPastaDisco = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* nomeImagem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dTeste",numero];

     caminhoImagemEmDisco = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",enderecoPastaDisco,nomeImagem];
    NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagemRecebida, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
    [data2 writeToFile:caminhoImagemEmDisco atomically:YES];
    // retorna imagem

    NSLog(@"CaminhoImagem: %@",caminhoImagemEmDisco);


    numero ++;
    }
}

-(NSString*)retornaImagem{


    return caminhoImagemEmDisco;

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Erro de request: %@",error);
}
@end
```

Como estou fazendo constantes testes para tentar solucionar, existem variáveis que não vão fazer sentido aparentemente. Mas o código em um todo pode ser compreendido.

Comment: Tiago, se você colocar o código usado para controle dos downloads fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Só uma dúvida: o que é WB?

Comment: @TiagoAmaral acho que não tem problema colar aqui. O campo de código tem scroll e fica tudo certinho.

Comment: Blz estarei adicionando então... so 2 min

Comment: Codigo adicionado, como comentei existem variáveis e comentários em pontos do código, que podem não fazer sentido pois estou testando o código de diversos modos.

 Sugiro a criação de um chat para esta questão...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contornei este impasse fazendo o download de imagens assíncrono e independente do download das Strings. Mas consecutivo ao termino do download de Strings. 
 Após baixar todos os objetos, é feito um separação das URL's em um array que é passado para  segunda classe que faz os downloads e salva as imagens em disco, retornado para o Core Data a path das imagens de cada objeto.

Utilizei mais um campo adicional, ID para fazer a busca dos dados, e um fetch para fazer update do banco, assim inserindo a path das imagens após o download.

Answer (score 0):

copiar string.

```
NSData * dadosBrutos=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://url.com.br/lista_noticias_db_json.php"]];
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dadosBrutos encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

copiar imagem..

```
NSData * imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://url.com.br/imagem.png"]];
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```